# Which one is bigger $100^{300}$ or $300!$?

Tags: asymptotics, arithmetic, exponentiation, factorial

How to find which one is bigger $100^{300}$ or $300!$ without using a calculator?
I have tried it for whole 2 years but could not find it yet.

Comment: Stirling's formula?

Comment: You tried for two years?  That is some dedication... or stubbornness...  In that amount of time I would have thought you could have found the exact values by hand.

Comment: Each is a product of three hundred factors. Did you think about taking their ratios?

Comment: Don't forget the error bound when using Stirling's formula.

Comment: @hardmath: Some of the ratios are greater than $1$, some smaller, and there doesn't seem to be an _obvious_ way to match them up such that one of the directions wins.

Comment: there is a sum-integral comparison that typically gives weak versions of known inequalities, but can be used in many situations and gives both upper and lower bounds. My sense is that this is no longer a guaranteed part of a calculus course, so i keep posting the simple picture...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let $n\in\Bbb N$. We have $e<3$ and hence
$$3^{3n}>e^{3n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(3n)^k}{k!}.$$
As all summands are positive, this implies 
$$ 3^{3n}>\frac{(3n)^k}{k!}=\frac{3^kn^k}{k!}$$
for all $k$. In particular, for $k=3n$, this becomes $3^{3n}>\frac{3^{3n}n^{3n}}{(3n)!}$, or
$$(3n)!>n^{3n}.$$
For $n=100$, this gives us
$$300! > 100^{300}. $$

Comment: +1: Cute. ${}{}$

Answer (score 3):

Easy general method needing no cleverness, useful for many problems, **See the diagram below**:
[image]

For a function such as (natural) logarithm with $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x) > 0,$  we get
$$  \int_{a-1}^b \; f(x) dx < \sum_{k=a}^b \; f(k) < \int_{a}^{b+1} \; f(x) dx $$

Here $f$ is log base e,  take $a=2$ and $b=n,$ later we will take $n=300$
$$  \int_{1}^n \; \log x \; dx < \sum_{k=2}^n \; \log k < \int_{2}^{n+1} \; \log x \; dx $$

An antiderivative of $\log x$ is $x \log x  - x.$

$$ n \log n - n + 1 < \log n! < (n+1) \log (n+1) - n - 1 - 2 \log 2 + 2 $$

$$ 300 \log 300 - 299 < \log 300! < 301 \log 301 - 299 -  \log 4  $$

$$ 300 ( \log 100 + \log 3)- 299 < \log 300!  $$

As $e \approx 2.71828 < 3,$ we find $1 < \log 3$ and $300 < 300 \log 3,$
$$ 300 \log 100 < 300 \log 100 + 300 - 299 < \log 300!  $$ 
$$ 100^{300} < 300! $$

Answer (score 0):

More generally, for positive integer $n$, we have

$$(3n)!>n^{3n},$$

and taking logs of both sides and rearranging, the inequality is equivalent to

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\log (k/n)>0.$$

This can be shown by noting the LHS is just a right Riemann sum for $\int_0^3 \log xdx$ and since $\log x$ is monotonically increasing, the right Riemann sum will be an overestimate of the integral so

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\log (k/n)>\int_0^3 \log xdx=3\log 3-3>3\log e-3=0.$$