# Stuck on an inequality proof involving a factorial

Tags: calculus, inequality

It appears to me that the inequality
$$(3n)!>n^{3n}$$
aught to hold for any positive integer $n$. (checking the first 1000 in wolfram alpha gave a sequece of rapidly rising positive values)

However, I am at a loss for how to prove it.

Might anyone have some tips as to how to go about proving it or finding a counterexample?
(bonus points for elementary methods not requiring $\exp$, $\ln$ etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Let $n\ge 1$. We have $e<3$ and hence
$$3^{3n}>e^{3n}$$
We can change the exponential formula in summation form as below:
$$e^x=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)$$
$$e^{3n}=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{(3n)^k}{k!}\right)$$
As all summands are positive, this implies
$$3^{3n}>\frac{\left(3n\right)^k}{k!}$$
$$3^{3n}>\frac{3^kn^k}{k!}$$
for all $k$. In particular, for $k=3n$, this becomes
$$3^{3n}>\frac{3^{3n}n^{3n}}{(3n)!}$$
$$(3n)!>\frac{3^{3n}n^{3n}}{3^{3n}}$$
$$(3n)!>n^{3n}$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3266679

Comment: I remember the OP explicitly asking for some hints. Hint: This is not a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Taking logs of both sides and rearranging, the inequality is equivalent to

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\log (k/n)>0.$$

Note the LHS is just a right Riemann sum for $\int_0^3 \log xdx$ and since $\log x$ is monotonically increasing, the right Riemann sum will be an overestimate of the integral so

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\log (k/n)>\int_0^3 \log xdx=3\log 3-3>3\log e-3=0.$$